# Как использовать REF тип данных в PL/SQL блоке или SQL запросе?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, database-cursor

В моем понимании `REF` это тип данных, который может хранить ссылку на значение объектного типа.

Создал такой тип данных:

```
create or replace type person as object (
    name   VARCHAR2 (20),
    age    NUMBER (4, 2))
/
```

С ним создал таблицу и вставил строку.

```
create table person_table of person;

insert into person_table values ('Sam', 24);
```

Как я могу использовать `REF` для хранения ссылки на вставленный объект в другой таблице, в PL/SQL блоке или в SQL запросе?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to use REF datatype in Oracle PL/SQL code or in SQL statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62167119/6571020) от участника [@Aman Singh Rajpoot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12937828/aman-singh-rajpoot)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/62167119/6571020

Answer (score 2):

Сказать точнее, `REF` это не тип данных, это ссылкa на конкретную запись в объектной таблице. Подробнеее о содержании и применени в подглаве [Design Considerations for REFs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/adobj/design-considerations-for-REFs.html#GUID-79DD95A2-3080-47BC-95FB-7FD42D1E1BBF).

Чтобы получить значение `REF` Надо воспользоваться одноимённой SQL функцией [REF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REF.html#GUID-B7622138-6EB6-4203-B5E7-91CAD52E9DB1):

> `REF` takes as its argument a correlation variable (table alias) associated with a row of an object table or an object view. A `REF` value is returned for the object instance that is bound to the variable or row.

Принимает как аргумент корреляцию (алиас таблицы) с записью объектной таблицы (или представления). Значение возврата можно сохранить в переменной или колонке таблицы.  Обратное преобразование с [DEREF](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/DEREF.html#GUID-E551FFE4-619F-40CE-8303-683EFA3EB28F).

---

В воспроизводимом примере ниже показаны почти все случаи использования `REF`.

```
create or replace type person force as object (
    name varchar2 (20), age int)
/    
create table persontab of person
/
create or replace type employee as object (
    dept varchar2 (8), hierdate date, pref REF person)
/
create table employeetab of employee
/
```

PL/SQL блок:

```
var rc refcursor;
declare 
    r ref person;
    p person;
begin null; 
    insert into persontab p values ('Bob', 33)
    returning ref (p) into r;
    insert into employeetab values ('IT-DEV', date'2020-01-01', r);
    
    open :rc for 
        select p.*, e.dept, e.hierdate, deref (e.pref) person 
        from employeetab e 
        join persontab p on ref (p) = e.pref; 
end;
/
```

Результат:

```
NAME                        AGE DEPT     HIERDATE            PERSON(NAME, AGE)       
-------------------- ---------- -------- ------------------- ------------------------
Bob                          33 IT-DEV   2020-01-01 00:00:00 PERSON('Bob', 33)
```

Answer (score 2):

Нужно просто использовать ключевое слово `REF` при создании таблицы, в которой будет храниться ссылка типа данных `PERSON` следующим образом:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE (PERSON_DETAILS REF PERSON);
```

и тогда можно вставить данные в эту таблицу, используя функцию `REF`, указав на `PERSON_TABLE`, которая сама по себе является таблицей с типом данных `PERSON`:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE
SELECT REF(P) FROM PERSON_TABLE P WHERE NAMES = 'Sam';
```

---

<sub>Свободный перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62167193) от участника [@ORA_Dentist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11565629/ora-dentist)</sub>